# Rolling windows without NaN at the beginning

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following code with rolling windows of 3:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({"date":['1/1/2021','1/2/2021','1/3/2021','1/4/2021','1/5/2021','1/1/2021','1/2/2021','1/3/2021','1/4/2021','1/5/2021'],"item_name":["bracelet","bracelet","bracelet","bracelet","bracelet","earring","earring","earring","earring","earring"],"quantity_sold":[1,2,3,4,5,100,200,300,400,500]})
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
display(df)
#sort on the right fields before the calculation
df=df.sort_values(['date','item_name'])
#sum of quantity for last 3 days (curr_day-2,curr_day-1,curr_day)
display(df.set_index("date").groupby("item_name").rolling(3).agg('sum'))
```

the result is:

[image]

Is it possible to have the first two value calculated without NaN - e.g., on `bracelet, 2021-01-01`, since we have 1 element, we use rolling windows of 1 and get `value=1`; on `bracelet, 2021-01-02`, since we have 2 element, we use rolling windows of 2 and get `value=3`?
(So similarly we have `bracelet, 2021-01-01` with `value =100` and  `bracelet, 2021-01-02` with `value =300`)

Comment: Could you explain the same with an expected output?

Comment: @anky expected output is the four NaN in the image becomes 1,3,100,300 from top to bottom, all other values are the same.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `min_periods` keyword from the [documentation of `rolling()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html):

```
df.set_index("date").groupby("item_name").rolling(3,min_periods=1).agg('sum')
```

> **min_periods: *int, default None***
>
> Minimum number of observations in window
> required to have a value (otherwise result is NA). For a window that
> is specified by an offset, min_periods will default to 1. Otherwise,
> min_periods will default to the size of the window.

This will give you:

```
                      quantity_sold
item_name date                     
bracelet  2021-01-01            1.0
          2021-01-02            3.0
          2021-01-03            6.0
          2021-01-04            9.0
          2021-01-05           12.0
earring   2021-01-01          100.0
          2021-01-02          300.0
          2021-01-03          600.0
          2021-01-04          900.0
          2021-01-05         1200.0
```